# next/prev buttons on background slider img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've been trying to create next/prev arrows on slider set as background but without success.

It must have automated slider with 4-5 sec switch, but I'd like to add option to use buttons/arrows and slide backgrounds.

Any help?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="homepage">
    <div class="fadein">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
        <img src="img/2.jpg">
        <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#homepage {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.fadein {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
    object-position: center;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 6000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created two buttons to previous/next actions:

```
<div id="homepage">
    <div class="fadein">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
        <img src="img/2.jpg">
        <img src="img/3.jpg">
    </div>

    <button onclick="previousSlide()">
      Previous
    </button>
    <button onclick="nextSlide()">
      Next
    </button>
</div>
```

Then one function for each button or you can refactor both with a single function if you like:

```
<script>
function previousSlide() {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().nextAll('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
}

function nextSlide() {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
}
</script>
```

This is the behavior you asked for, now if you want to use `img` or `div` instead you just need to change the buttons for them.

Comment: Previous button function has some glitch, when you try to go backwards it starts flipping images in some weird way. Not sure what's happening. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Here is the code to add previous/next actions.

<button id= "plus" class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button id= "plus2"
            class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
```